# how to put if statement inside a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a if statament in a variabile to manipulate. I don't know how to execute and to store the answer in a variable and then to echo the variable.I try with quote around but not work and this:

```
    $conditie_variabila = {
    if(isset($var1))
    {
    echo "variabila este setata";
    }
};


echo $conditie_variabila;
```

Please help!

Comment: You can't do this. You assign values into a variable in if statement. You can see many examples of if statement on net.

Comment: This approach will not work. You need to think the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put it the other way around. Like this:

```
if(isset($var1)) {
  $conditie_variabla = "variabla este setata";
};
echo $conditie_variabla;
```

Or like this:

```
$conditie_variabila = isset($var1) ? "variabila este setata" : "variabla nu este setata";
echo $conditie_variabila;
```

To be honest, that last example is somewhat close to what you where looking for.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: @DanutMarianGabrian: Would you please consider accepting this answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you still want the function inside a variable try something like this:

```
$var1 = "hi";   
$test = "foo";
$test($var1);

function foo($var1){
    if(isset($var1))
    {
    echo "variabila este setata";
    }
}
```

Tested and produces your required result